# 'ng2-pdf-viewer' not working for local pdf in iOS with Ionic 3

Tags: android, ios, pdf, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am using ng2-pdf-viewer in Ionic application to view PDF, it is perfectly working with Android but giving issue in iOS.
I am passing file URL as 'assets/doc/sample.pdf'. Not throwing any event like error, progress, rendered etc.
External URL is working perfectly in iOS

Comment: Hi, have you solved this? I'm currently facing the same. Can you please help me with it?